# Delete user using firebase Admin SDK

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-admin-sdk

How do I delete a user from my admin panel using the firebase Admin SDK? I'm getting this error when trying to delete it:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: uid is not defined
> at eval (ManageCustomer.vue?b113:262)

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code in index.js from functions

```
 const functions = require("firebase-functions");
    const admin = require("firebase-admin");
    admin.initializeApp();
    const db = admin.firestore();
    
    exports.AddUserRole = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (authUser) => {
      if (authUser.email) {
        const customClaims = {
          //admin: true,
          customer: true,
        };
        try {
          var _ = await admin
            .auth()
            .setCustomUserClaims(authUser.uid, customClaims);
          return db
            .collection("roles")
            .doc(authUser.uid)
            .set({
              email: authUser.email,
              role: customClaims,
            });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      }
    });
    
    exports.deleteUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
      if (!context.auth.token.admin) return    
      try {
        var _ = await admin
          .auth()
          .deleteUser(uid)
          .then(() => {
            console.log("Successfully deleted user");
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error deleting user:", error);
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error deleting user", error);
      }
    });
```

Here is my client side code

```
   <template>
  <div class="manage-customer">
    <br />
    <div>
      <h2>Customer</h2>
      <br />

      <section>
        <div class="">
          <div class="column">
            <div>
              <div class="header" style=" font-weight: bold;">
                Customer Info
              </div>
              <router-link to="/admin/new-user" class="btn" href="#">
                New User</router-link
              >

              <table class="table table-users" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                  <tr style=" text-align: center;">
                    <th
                      style="background: var(--primary); color: var(--secondary); width:180px "
                    >
                      User Id
                    </th>
                    <th
                      style="background: var(--primary); color: var(--secondary); width:180px"
                    >
                      Username
                    </th>
                    <th
                      style="background: var(--primary); color: var(--secondary); width:120px"
                    >
                      Email
                    </th>
                    <th
                      style="background: var(--primary); color: var(--secondary); width:150px"
                    >
                      Phone
                    </th>
                    <th
                      style="background: var(--primary); color: var(--secondary); width:220px"
                    >
                      Address
                    </th>
                    <th
                      style="background: var(--primary); color: var(--secondary); width:60px"
                    >
                      Postcode
                    </th>
                    <th
                      style="background: var(--primary); color: var(--secondary); width:170px; "
                    >
                      Action
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr v-for="profile in profiles" :key="profile.id">
                    <td data-label="Id" style="width: 160px;">
                      {{ profile.id }}
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="DisplayName" style="width: 150px">
                      {{ profile.displayName }}
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Email" style="width: 150px">
                      {{ profile.email }}
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Phone" style="width: 100px">
                      {{ profile.phone }}
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Address" style="width: 250px">
                      {{ profile.address }}
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Postcode" style="width: 70px">
                      {{ profile.postcode }}
                    </td>
                    <td
                      style="width:170px; display:inline-flex;"
                      data-label="Action"
                    >
                      <button
                        @click="editProfile(profile)"
                        class="edit-product"
                        style=" "
                      >
                        Edit
                      </button>

                      <button
                        class="delete-product"
                        @click="deleteProfile(profile)"
                        style=""
                      >
                        Delete
                      </button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>

              <br />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <modal
        name="profiles"
        style="top: 10px; margin: 0 auto;"
        height="80%"
        width="65%"
        :adaptive="true"
      >
        <div class="container">
          <div class="modal-body-product">
            <form style=" width: 90% !important; border: 0;  box-shadow: none;">
              <div>
                <span @click="hide" class="close">&#10006;</span>
              </div>
              <!-- <h3 id="productLabel">Add Profile</h3> -->
              <h3 id="productLabel" style="margin-bottom: 1.5rem;">
                EDIT PROFILE
              </h3>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Username:</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Username"
                  v-model.lazy="profile.displayName"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Phone:</label>
                <input
                  name="description"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Phone"
                  v-model.lazy="profile.phone"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Address:</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Address"
                  v-model.lazy="profile.address"
                  class="form-control"
                />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Postcode:</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Postcode"
                  v-model.lazy="profile.postcode"
                  class="form-control"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <!-- <button
                  class="btn"
                  type="button"
                  @click.prevent="addProfile()"
                  @click="hide"
                >
                  Save
                </button> -->
                <br />
                <button class="btn" type="button" @click="updateProfile()">
                  Apply changes
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </modal>
    </div>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import firebase from "firebase";
// const admin = require("firebase-admin");
// admin.initializeApp();
// const db = admin.firestore();
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
window.Swal = Swal;

const Toast = Swal.mixin({
  toast: true,
  position: "top-end",
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 3000,
});

window.Toast = Toast;

export default {
  name: "Dashboard",
  data() {
    return {
      users: [],
      user: "",
      roles: [],
      profiles: [],
      profile: {
        id: null,
        displayName: null,
        phone: null,
        address: null,
        postcode: null,
      },
      activeItem: null,
    };
  },
  firestore() {
    return {
      profiles: firebase.firestore().collection("profiles"),
      roles: firebase.firestore().collection("roles"),
    };
  },

  created() {
    var self = this;
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      self.user = user;
    });
    this.users = [];
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("roles")
      .get()
      .then((snap) => {
        snap.forEach((doc) => {
          var user = doc.data();
          user.id = doc.id;
          console.log("", doc.data());
          if (!user.role.admin) this.users.push(user);
        });
      });
  },
  methods: {
    // addNew() {
    //   this.$router.push("/admin/new-user");
    // },
    hide() {
      this.$modal.hide("profiles");
    },
    editProfile(profile) {
      // this.modal = "edit";
      this.profile = profile;
      this.activeItem = profile.id;
      this.$modal.show("profiles");
    },
    updateProfile() {
      this.$firestore.profiles.doc(this.profile.id).update(this.profile);
      Toast.fire({
        icon: "success",
        title: "Profile updated successfully",
      });
      this.$modal.hide("profiles");
    },
    deleteProfile(doc) {
      Swal.fire({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        icon: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
        cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
          this.$firestore.profiles.doc(doc.id).delete();
          // console.log(doc.id);
          this.$firestore.roles.doc(doc.id).delete();
          const uid = this.profile.id;

          var deleteUser = firebase.functions().httpsCallable("deleteUser");
          deleteUser({ uid }) // not deleteUser(uid)
            .then((result) => {
              console.log("User delete successfully", result);
            });

          Toast.fire({
            icon: "success",
            title: "Deleted successfully",
          });
        }
      });
    },
   
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not accessing the UID in your cloud function from the data object.

```
exports.deleteUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
      if (!context.auth.token.admin) return   
      const {uid} = data;
      if (!uid) return {error: "Please enter an UID"} 
      try {
        // return the promise from here
        await admin.auth().deleteUser(uid)
        await admin.firestore().collection("profiles").doc(uid).delete()
        console.log("Successfully deleted user");
        return {data: "User deleted"}   
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error deleting user", error);
        return {error}
      }
    });
```

Also try passing the UID from Vue app in an object as shown in the documentation.

```
const uid = "uidOfUserToBeDeleted"

var deleteUser = firebase.functions().httpsCallable("deleteUser");
deleteUser({uid}) // not deleteUser(uid)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log("User delete successfully", result);
  })
```

However, the issue is on your frontend. Where is `uid` defined? In the example above I have hard coded it, make sure you fetch the UID from your input field if it is an admin that is trying to delete user.

Is the `doc.id` the UID of user to be deleted? If yes, then you should call function like this `deleteUser(doc.id)`

Comment: Hi, I'm having a firestore collection of user profiles and roles - two collections. rn im only able to delete users from my collection but not the actual user on the firebase authentication table. I tried the code above it kinda runs (user does not get deleted tho) but I'm also getting this error: User deleted successfully 
Object
data: {error: "Please enter an UID"}
__proto__: Object

Comment: @RuznaRizvi are you calling the function with the UID as I mentioned in my answer? Try hardcoding the uid: `deleteUser("theUIDToDelete")` in your Vue app

Comment: tried it but im getting some firebase missing insuffiicient permissions error although I have the security rules written for it already. I didnt get this error when I used the same collection to edit users in admin panel

Comment: @RuznaRizvi Admin SDK does not follow any security rules. I'd recommend deleting the Firestore document from the cloud function as well. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks brother. Your code kinda helped me solve my prob, except for a few changes here and there. It finally works! :)